# HP Laptop keyboard and touchpad shut off randomly

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, touchpad

It's an HP Pavilion DV7 (AMD quad-core) and it's HD has just been replaced. OS was loaded from OEM disks.

Now, the keyboard and touchpad just stop working after a few seconds to quite a few minutes of use. USB devices are fine (mouse/keyboard).

Event Viewer shows lots of these:

```
Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service kbdhid for 
Device Instance ID HID\VID_046D&PID_C52E&MI_00\7&18736074&0&0000 with the 
following status: 0.
```

and

```
Driver Management concluded the process to install driver 
FileRepository\keyboard.inf_amd64_neutral_0684fdc43059f486\keyboard.inf 
for Device Instance ID HID\VID_046D&PID_C52E&MI_00\7&18736074&0&0000 
with the following status: 0x0.
```

(Multiple times at the same timestamp). But I don't know if that's normal or not. I know software, not hardware.

In addition, the wireless USB keyboard cuts out randomly, but not the (separate) wireless USB mouse. Unplugging and replugging the USB dongle wakes it up again.

Device manager never shows any errors on the kbd/trackpad.

Mostly I'm asking where to look for the source of the problem. Motherboard connections disturbed during HD replacement? (Seems unlikely, with HD mounted under easy access port.) Some other thing I can diagnose with Windows tools? Some other tool to help diagnose it?